# During startup consume api only once

Tags: c#, .net

During the app startup I'm consuming `CarService` class in order to retrieve data.
I want to do this only once and that result `List<Car>` to be available from that point on to all consumers in the app (using DI), in other words I don't want to call CarService -> GetData every time when I inject `ICarService` in the controller or service but rather only once.

```
public interface ICarService
{
   Task<List<Car>> GetData();
}

public class CarService : ICarService
{
   private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

   public CarService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
   {
      _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
   }

   public async Task<List<Car>> GetData()
   { 
      var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
      var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:5011/cars");        
      var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
      ...
      return data;
   }
}
```

Program.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<ICarService, CarService>();
services.AddHostedService<GetDataService>();

public class GetDataService : IHostedService
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var carService = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<ICarService>();
        var data = carService.GetData();
        ...
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to implement some sort of caching layer. If it's in the cache then return it else fetch it from `CarService`

Comment: One approache could be to implement a caching mechanism (in memory / distributed) and cache it without expiration. So whenever you call GetData() it will return the cached data, except in the very first call, where it will fetch the live response.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `StartAsync` part is ok, the actual issue is that I don't want to call `GetData()` every time (whenever I inject `ICarService`) over the wire but rather only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing your CarService like this:

```
public class CarService : ICarService
{
   private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
   private Task<List<Car>> _getDataTask = null;

   public CarService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
   {
      _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
   }

   public Task<List<Car>> GetData()
   { 
      // Add some synchronization code if needed (semaphore, lock, mutex...)
      _getDataTask = _getDataTask ?? GetDataImpl();
      return _getDataTask;
   }

   private async Task<List<Car>> GetDataImpl()
   { 
      var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
      var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:5011/cars");        
      var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
      ...
      return data;
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works when the instance of `CarService` is a singleton. Another solution is to make the private field static.